# Cannot find symbol SetUtils in java

Tags: java, set

```
for (Set<Integer> s : SetUtils.powerSet(mySet))
```

I tried running the above code, but SetUtils variable was not found.
I am using Java 1.8.

What should I import to run the above statement?

Comment: SetUtils is not part of the Java SE 1.8 API. You'll need to add the Apache Commons Collections library as a JAR, and import `org.apache.commons.collections4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should import `org.apache.commons.collections4.SetUtils`.

If your IDE didn't handled adding the library see this
[How do I learn to use Java commons-collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656989/how-do-i-learn-to-use-java-commons-collections) to learn how to use that in your project.

You can find required `jar` files from [apache site](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi).